# C++, array of objects (from different classes) without Stl & Boost

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to create in C++ an array which can hold objects of diffrent classes.

It's a part of my hometask and one of the conditions is that i can't use Stl, Boost & etc.

Comment: This is a Question & Answer site, and you are a bit low on Question.

Comment: Taken literally this is impossible, as an *array* by definition can only ever be an array of objects of one fixed type.

Comment: What lesson have you been taught in relation to this homework? It's unusual to hold different classes of object as you can't handle them uniformly, unless you're using inheritance or templates? Is that what you're learning about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create Base class and derive your class from Base class. And as a result you can create array `Base*` array and put there all derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

You could store pointers to `void*` in your array and cast your objects to `void*`. But you should not do this!

If possible you should  derive all your objects from a Base Class and store pointers to `Base*`. This is the better way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does the same container have to hold objects of the same type at the same time? If so, does it have to be able to hold any type? If so, your only solution is to use `void*` and store pointers to the objects you want to store.

If one container only has to hold one type of object, then you can do this using templates. If the same container has to hold different types of objects *but* you can place restrictions on the types it can hold, then you can make a requirement be that it derive from some `Base` class, and make an array of `Base*`.